# Ontario Sales Tax Transition Benefit: Can you still get first cheque even if 2009 taxes are filed later?

Tags: canada, ontario, hst, rebate

If a person hasn't filed his or her tax return for 2009 before the cheques are mailed out in June 2010, will they still receive the payment after they file the return, or are they out of luck?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to exactly this question at the Ontario Ministry of Revenue.

In a nutshell: **Yes** you can still get the first cheque even if you file your taxes late.  The Ministry will process your payment within 8 weeks after your return has been processed by the Canada Revenue Agency.  **However, don't delay very long – there is a cut-off point (one year late filing) beyond which you forfeit the benefits!**

Here's the Ministry's FAQ about this:

> **I filed my 2009 and 2010 returns late. Do I still qualify for OSTTB benefit?**
>
> The information provided on your
>   income tax return is used to calculate
>   the OSTTB  eligibility and payment
>   amounts. Thus, **late filed returns will
>   delay OSTTB eligibility calculations
>   and related payments. You can expect
>   OSTTB payments due, within 8 weeks
>   after you receive the [Notice of Assessment](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/ncm-tx/chngrtrn-eng.html)
>   from CRA.
>
> There are also deadlines for filing
>   late 2009 and 2010 returns for OSTTB
>   purposes. You are allowed one year to
>   file after the 2009 and 2010 filing
>   due dates:
>
> - You will **not** receive the June 10, 2010 and December 2010 OSTTB
>     benefits if your 2009 return is filed
>     later then **April 30, 2011** and
> - You will **not** receive the June 2011 OSTTB benefit if your 2010 return
>     is filed later then **April 30, 2012**.
>
>   *[emphasis mine]*

You'll [find the original FAQ here](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/credit/sttb/faq_eligibility.html#Q12).