# Ontario HST rebate: Do you still get the HST cheque if only one spouse has filed their taxes?

Tags: canada, ontario, hst, rebate

What happens if one spouse has filed their taxes and the other has not? Do you still get the family HST rebate cheque?

Comment: Thank You, This really helped answer my question, I have not filed for 2008 yet. And I have some income problems right now because I am laid off. I wanted to know if I would still get back paid for the cheques I missed over the last year. I have also not recieved a GST cheque for two years.If anyone has gone through this already (reside in Ontario) Please let me know. I would like to know what I am in for.
Thanks again

Comment: @KlaneO This is a Q&A site which is a little different than a web forum.  You'll find better answers by first searching through the [hst questions](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hst) and if you don't find your specific question, click on "Ask Question" at the top right of the page.

Comment: @KlaneO File your late returns, and call Canada Revenue Agency.  Without your tax returns filed, CRA won't pay you these benefits (they don't know you qualify.)

Answer (score 2):

I can tell that judging by the fact that the $330 was deposited today that the answer is yes.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back.  Perhaps Canada Revenue Agency based it on other information on file (T4 income, or last year's return) for the missing return ... or they just aren't as diligent as I expected they might be.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question.  I couldn't find definitive information on it, so your best bet for a certain answer is to [call the Canada Revenue Agency at 1 877 627-6645](https://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/credit/sttb/faq_general.html#Q7).

However, here's my thinking on the subject:

- As a couple, it's possible to receive **no** HST rebate benefit **if family net income exceeds $166,700.**  Refer to the "phase out range" in the table at [this other question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1224/ontario-special-hst-sales-tax-transition-rebate-cheques-who-when-how-much).
- If Canada Revenue Agency only has *one* of the two tax returns needed for a couple, (and presumably they know they're dealing with a couple based on previous filings or the one current filing), then *how are they to know if the couple qualifies or not?*  The second tax return could, in theory, place the couple's combined net income over the threshold!
- Therefore: I would assume that if CRA is missing half of the story, they would not send *any* HST transition cheque at all, since there's a *chance* the spouse's missing income could totally disqualify the couple from any benefits.

While that seems *logical* to me, I can't confirm that's how it actually works.

But there's some good news: late filers can still qualify for a benefit.  Refer to: [Ontario Sales Tax Transition Benefit: Can you still get first cheque even if 2009 taxes are filed later?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1718/ontario-sales-tax-transition-benefit-can-you-still-get-first-cheque-even-if-2009)

Answer (score 1):

I did not get mine because my husband did not file 2009 return yet.
I called and they told me it would follow aprox. 8-10 weeks after filing his return.